# Mapped Google sites with a custom domain wiki.mydomain.com but don't want to see https://sites.google.com/a/mydomain/wiki eventually

Tags: google-cloud-platform, g-suite

I mapped my subdomain wiki.mydomain.com (through Godaddy) with https://sites.google.com/a/mydomain/wiki. Works great. However eventually the URL on the browser remains https://sites.google.com/a/mydomain/wiki after DNS forward.

I want to use Google sites but want to keep my subdomain URL throughout. So no more https://sites.google.com/a/mydomain/wiki kind of prefix. Instead wiki.mydomain.com kind of prefix throughout.

Looking for ideas on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could be done using domain masking. Domain name masking will allow you to show one URL in the browser's address bar, while another URL's content is being displayed in the browser. As per your requirement, when someone opens your website, you can have wiki.mydomain.com showing up in the browser's address bar while the actual content is from https://sites.google.com/a/mydomain/wiki

You could achieve this goal by simply changing your index.html file.The whole idea is using HTML frameset, and when you use the frameset, you split the visual real estate of a browser window into multiple frames in the browser. Inside the frame you would show content of a different site/URL.

For more details on Frames  review [this document on HTML - Frames](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_frames.htm) I found on the internet. For example

```
<html><head>
<title>Your page Title</title>
</head>
<frameset rows="100%,0" border="0">
<frame src="https://sites.google.com/a/mydomain/wiki " frameborder="0">
<frame frameborder="0">
</frameset>
</html>
```